# Estimating parameters of correlated random variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, estimation

Let's say there are two correlated random variables $X$ and $Y$ with coefficient of correlation as $r$.
Assume during some hypothesis testing we found that due to some change in the environment mean $\mu_x$ of $X$ has jumped by 25%. What will be the change in the $\mu_y$ of $Y$ which is also affected by a new change in a similar way? What will be the confidence interval in this case.

Comment: If the mean of $X$ has changed, then the distribution of $(X,Y)$ has changed, so you can no longer say anything about $E[Y].$

Comment: We have the sample for $X$ after the process change but not for $Y$. What I am saying is we knew earlier the correlation exists, now when we see due to some underlying process change which affects both equally mean of $X$ is changed(observed). Can we estimate how much the mean of $Y$ will change?

Comment: Not with that little information.  You would have to make strong assumptions to justify any estimate, assumptions that are tantamount to supposing there is a linear relationship between $X$ and the conditional expectation of $Y$ that is preserved by the process change.

Comment: Let us take an example. $X$ was the mean revenue for an app released on the android platform,  $Y$ is for the same app on IOS. A new change has caused $\mu_x$ to go up by 25% anything can be said about $Y$? May be a most likely estimate if not correct?

Comment: Little can be said at all about $Y.$ For instance, if the platforms compete, possibly $Y$ *decreases.*